# What's the type of "any" component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to define the type of component. It doesn't matter how many props it receives, is it a class or a function component, I don't even care if it returns a JSX element or just null or any string.

All I want to say is "a component", which is defined by React as anything that may have a key prop and a ref prop. I tried using `React.Component`:

```
  function Ramadan(){
    return <></>
  }

  const templatesMap: { [key: string]: React.Component } = {
    ramadan: Ramadan,
    adha: () => <></>,
    fitir: () => <></>,
    unset: () => <></>,
    mothers: () => <></>,
    birthDay: () => <></>,
  }
```

but TypeScript is showing the following error:

```
Type '() => Element' is not assignable to type 'Component<{}, {}, any>'.ts(2322)
WriteContent.tsx(10, 25): The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

Comment: The error you are getting is because `Ramadan` fn returns `undefined`, what about returning `<></>` in `Ramadan`?

Comment: @RobertRendell, nah, that's not true, ok partially it's true, I updated my question my mistake

Comment: Hmm `JSX.Element` instead of `React.Component`?

Comment: `React.Component` is the type for the _class_ components, which you're not actually using. @RobertRendell `JSX.Element` is the type of the _element_, what the function component or (for class components) the render method returns, not the _component_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `React.ComponentType` which is typed as:

```
React.ComponentClass<P, any> | React.FunctionComponent<P>
```

Example:

```
function Ramadan(){
  return <></>
}

const templatesMap: { [key: string]: React.ComponentType<any> } = {
  ramadan: Ramadan,
  adha: () => <></>,
  fitir: React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <></>),
  unset: class MyClassComp extends React.Component { 
    render() { return <></> } 
  },
  mothers: () => null,
  birthDay: () => <></>,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoczAVwDsNgJbEUQUATFWgCgEoBvcnDhEY1KMwA8APkkB6aeQC+lNEwDO8GEnAAbFNvUBZFGABccfnADaAayQBPC5qjBaAcwC6F5OhgA6AGFcSFokWhgAFQcwJEkuB2k4JTgAXkshEVYOLh9szloAGkyOAAsUCz40pJl5aWLhTGAYYCgfYgDMaAB3FCh2ZExubjAcMHVCkSRMXmqM4WE1Wk1LOExktLhRiHGKBamxCThahUylXga4OnUkGAs0fXV1OCMHQMf1YPA4JAAPbVo7GevgwQRCTHC8CsmWEREBSCgVSsonEUlkCg2Z0uIAgMFKCPUlVmqSStGoul0lwARq08QARFBOOBVEnHdH1ZSUGj0FpMF5vEJIzJLFZfMCbbR6AxIYymfxQfJcPYHVHHMVwewOVIAIhADgA0o5tXBTkogA)

Comment: one enhancement, I think it's `React.ComponentType<any>` instead of just `React.ComponentType`

Comment: Great, but it's missing the key prop.

Comment: I don't think so, see this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoczAVwDsNgJbEUQUATFWgCgEoBvcnDhEY1KMwA8APkkB6aeQC+lNEwDO8GEnAAbFNvUBZFGABccfnADaAayQBPC5qjBaAcwC6F5OhgA6AGFcSFokWhgAFQcwJDglOABeSyERVg4uH3TOWgAaVI4ACxQLPiTpOBl5aXzhTGAYYCgfYgDMaAB3FCh2ZExubjAcMHVckSRMXnLK2QVeWrg6dSQYCzR9dXU4IwdAjfVg8DgkAA9tWnYt3wwgkKZw+CtU4SILpCgyq1FxKVmKhNSSgWIAgMEK73UpSmiQqtGoul0CwARk0wQARFBOOBlGEzar5FRUOgMJjbXYhT6pNS0TRwQ5gJJwbR6AxIYymfxQbJcCgvFY-Sr0uD2ByJABEIAcAGlHGK4AplEA)